# Why when using Unity.Mvc3 and the UnitOfWork pattern do I get the .."different ObjectContext objects" error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, unity-container

I first have to say we are experimenting with removing our DTO layer and strictly using entities. Reason being, we tried several different mappers and they all caused performance issues. This is to be expected if you have large data sets and have many complex objects.

So, we are employing the UnitOfWork pattern and are wondering why we might be getting the "The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects." error. Unity is taking care of serving up the correct UnitOfWork and we even put a Version code on the UoW to make sure it is the same one getting passed around. And we can't find that there is a different one anywhere.

Without getting into our code, has anyone else had this same experience using the Unity.MVC3 DependencyResolver and teh UoW getting instanited more than once? We are using the HierarchicalLifetimeManager on the UoW.

Comment: Without the container setup and some usage example where the exception occurs it's very hard tell where it goes wrong... Maybe the problem is around the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` because if you are using child container it will create a new instance of UoW for each child container.

Comment: @nemesv, I know it is difficult to know without seeing the code, I was hoping someone may have had an issue using unity in this way. No child containers are being created. We checked that too.